# Author ID mistaken with node id

Tags: views

I am making a website where certain users can create events. They can also create a page with information about their events in general. On the bottom of the general events page, I would like to display all events created by that user.

I am working with EVA do fetch all events. I thought I should make a contextual filter, targetting the author:id(110), but this doesn't work. When I debug, I notice that Views thinks the author id(should be 110) is the node id(=56). Am I doing something wrong?

Kind regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the EVA Field display of the View you'll see a section there called "*Entity content settings*." Make sure the settings there are as follows:

a. Entity type: Node
b. Bundles: select the event type content type that you want to appear at the bottom.
c. Arguments: Choose: "Use tokens from the entity the view is attached to" and then add the following token (with brackets) where it asks for the token: [node:author:uid]

2. Now set the *contextual filter* for the EVA field display as follows:
   Author uid
   with the following setting: 
   Provide default value: User ID from URL.
3. Optionally, if you want to include something like "Events created by Jane Smith" at the top of the EVA view, then you need to add a relationship to the User. Then in the "Fields" section add user name and set it to "Exclude from display." Create a header for the view and choose "Global text" and check on the functionality to allow the use of tokens in the text. The user name token will be [name].

That's it. You'll be good.

I think it is worth to note what's a bit confusing here. It might help you to remember next time.
a. "User ID from URL" is really a misnomer. It's getting the User id from the node. The user id is not in the URL at all.
b. It feels like the filter/argument is being set twice; once in the Entity settings and then again in the Contextual filter settings.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. Note that under Bundles, I had to choose the general event content type.